# $\log_{2} (3 \sin \theta) = 2.\log_{2}(-3\cos \theta) + 1$ what's the sum of possible $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

$0 \leq \theta \leq 360$

$\log_{2} (3 \sin \theta) = 2.\log_{2}(-3\cos \theta) + 1$

$\log_{2} 3 + \log_{2} \sin \theta = \log_{2} 9 + \log_{2} \cos ^2 \theta + \log_{2} 2$

$\log_{2} \sin \theta - \log_{2} \cos ^2 \theta = \log_{2} 6$

$\log_{2} \sin ^3 \theta = \log_{2} 6$

How to find the possible angle?

Comment: That step from $\log_2\sin\theta - \log_2\cos^2\theta$ to $\log_2\sin^3\theta$ looks wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly we need $\sin\theta>0,\cos\theta<0$

$$\implies90^\circ<\theta<180^\circ$$

Choose $180^\circ-\theta=t$

$$\log_2(3\sin t)=2\log_2(3\cos t)+1=\log_2(2(3\cos t)^2)$$

$$3\sin t=18(1-\sin ^2t)$$